# Positioning a dropdown in plotly

Tags: html, css, r, plotly

I want to position a dropdown menu under the legend. However depending on how big the plot in terms of resolution is, `plotly` changes the position of this dropdown (cf. uploaded pictures).

The first plot shows the output like it appears in the little Rstudio 
plot tab. The second shows how far the dropdown goes to the right if I switch to fullscreen.

**How can I fix the position of the dropdown menu?** Any solution is appreciated whether it is `html`, `R` or anything else

[image: Dropdown is too far left]

[image: Dropdown is too far right]

Below you can find the code which I used to create the plots:

```
library(plotly)
x <- seq(-2 * pi, 2 * pi, length.out = 1000)
df <- data.frame(x, y1 = sin(x), y2 = cos(x),tan_h=tanh(x))

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~y1, name = "sin") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~y2, name = "cos") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~tan_h, name='tanh',visible=FALSE) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Drop down menus - Styling",
    xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        x = 1.1,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "Cos"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)),
               label = "Tanh"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)),
               label = "All")

          ))
    )
  )
```

Comment: maybe you could set a position with `xanchor`and `yanchor`.

Comment: If you wanted to do it manually using HTML/CSS the classes are `legend` and `updatemenu-container`. I can't remember exactly how, but you can add custom HTML/CSS to a `htmlwidget` object before rendering - I'll see if I can find out how later

Comment: @MLavoie: I tried `xanchor='center'` and `yanchor='middle'`. Don't know why but it doesn't affect the position at all. I also thought if x and y are normalised coordinates that this should work. But somehow it doesn't.

Comment: @aocall I fear your way is the only way which may work. However as far as I understand it the classes `legend` and `updatemenu-container` have different `translate`-functions. Therefore I didn't see how a positioning via css can work.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old now, but for Python you now at least can position this via the plotly API, as per: https://plotly.com/python/v3/dropdowns/#style-dropdown

You can pass the arguments `x`, `y`, `xanchor` and `yanchor` to the `updatemenus` argument of the plotly `graphobjects` `Figure`'s `update_layout` method:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(
    title="Demo",
    updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
        active=0,
        buttons=[{"label": "Demo button...", "args": [{"showlegend": False}]}],
        x = 0.3,
        xanchor = 'left',
        y = 1.2,
        yanchor = 'top',
    )
                ]
)
fig.show()
```